# this number is formated as text using inputbox

Tags: text, vbscript, numbers

I have this input box that collect amounts and then enters them in a cell:

```
Dim DEKPOSO As String
DEKPOSO = InputBox("enter the ammount?")

Sheets("ammounts").Range("E3").Value = DEKPOSO
```

When you enter the amount as 450.23 everything is fine, the cell registers as 450,23

The problem is I am in Greece and when I enter the amount 450.23 in the inputbox as normal (when greek language is selected) it displays in the cell correctly but it shows an error that the number is formated as text and partly won't calculate.

Comment: Have you tried to use `CStr` or `CDbl` functions?

Comment: I think I did but it returned whole number without the decimal eg 450

Comment: and the double corrects the problem but when entering with a dot eg 450.23 it converts it without the coma eg 45023 whole number without comma

Comment: Not that clean, but have you try to simply use replace(DEKPOSO, ".", ",") or the opposite, to force dot or comma according to your regional settings ?